Error al subir proyecto Laravel con VUE js a servidor web
Anteriormente subi un proyecto creado en Laravel a un servidor web, todo funciona bien hasta ahi, hace unos dias se agrego una nueva integracion, para la cual se utilizo componentes de VueJS, al cargarlo en el servidor todos los nuevos archivos no manda error, pero no se ven los cambios que se realizaron, y en consola muestra component mounted, lo cual se ve por default, por lo que considero no se actualizan los cambios, ya ejecute npm run build, pero no funciona, se que soy nuevo y el error que cometo es algo que puede ser de manual, pero si alguien pudiera decir alguna solucion, ya que estos dias he leido e investigado en todos lados y no he podido resolver el problema.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! falta info... que quiere decir que no funciona npm run build?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
